# how to delete the multiple record with checkbox

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

Here user should be able to select multiple contacts by checking the checkboxes and on clicking delete contact button, all the selected contacts should be deleted.

**VisualForce Page:**

```
   <apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="ViewController">
<apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Account Section">

            <apex:outputText value="Select Account" />
            <apex:selectList value="{!selVal}" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!AllAccount}" />
            </apex:selectList>
            <apex:commandButton value="View Contacts" action="  {!showRelatedContacts}" />
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>

    <apex:pageBlock title="Contact Section">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
            <apex:commandButton value="DeleteContacts" action="  {!DeleteChecked}" />
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contacts}" var="cont">
            <apex:column>
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!checked}" />
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column value="{!cont.name}" />
            <apex:column value="{!cont.email}" />
            <apex:column value="{!cont.phone}" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable>

    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

**Controller:**

```
public class ViewController {
                public String selVal {get;set;}
                public list < contact > contacts {get;set;}
                public list < selectOption > AllAccount {get;set;}
                public boolean checked {get;set;}
                public list < contact > dltcontacts {get;set;}
                public ViewController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
                    AllAccount = new list < selectOption > ();
                    list < account > acnts = [select id, name from account];
                    for (accounT ac: acnts) {
                        AllAccount.add(new selectOption(ac.id, ac.name));
                    }
                }
                public void showRelatedContacts() {
                    contacts = [select name, email, phone from contact where accountid =: selVal];
                }
                public void DeleteChecked() {
                    dltcontacts = new list < contact > ();
                    for (cont cc: contacts) {
                        if (cc.checked == true) {
                            delete cont;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

please suggest me to delete checked record

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Wrapper class to do this kind of functionality.

First create a Wrapper class at the end of your controller

```
public class ContactWrapper {
    public Contact contact {get; set;}
    public Boolean checked {get; set;}
    public ContactWrapper(Contact contact, Boolean checked){
        this.contact = contact;
        this.checked = checked;
    }
}
```

Then wherever you used `List<Contact>` replace it with `List<ContactWrapper>`

```
public list<contact> contacts {get; set;} ==> public List<ContactWrapper> contactsWrapper {get; set;}
```

Then you need to change the way `List<Contact>` is populated to populate `List<ContactWrapper>`

```
public void   showRelatedContacts(){    
    for(Contact contact : [select  name,email,phone from contact  where   accountid=:selVal]){
        contactsWrapper.add(new ContactWrapper(contact,false));
    }
}
```

Then you need to change the delete method to check for checked boolean in ContactWrapper to be true and delete only those contacts

```
public void DeleteChecked(){    
    dltcontacts=new list<contact>();
    for(ContactWrapper cc: contactsWrapper){
        if(cc.checked){
            dltcontacts.add(cc.contact);
        }
    }
    delete dltcontacts;         
}
```

In VF, you only have to change the way the contacts are iterated and values are shown

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contactsWrapper}" var="cont">
    <apex:column>
        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!cont.checked}" />
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column value="{!cont.contact.name}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!cont.contact.email}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!cont.contact.phone}"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

If you directly do any changes in controller, it will give you errors while saving the controller as the variables you removed (contacts) will still be used in VF page. So comment the VF code, do the changes in controller, save it and uncomment VF and do the changes and save it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: If the provided solution solved your problem, mark it as accepted so that others with same problem get benefited. Thanks.

Comment: yeahh vigneshh my issues solved with that provided sollution.....thanks once again..